# Any way to check opencv version in iOS project?

Tags: ios, opencv

In the iOS project (with no cocoaPods), openCV is used.

And the one who create this project can not be contacted because he went to other company.

I realized in the project, openCV framework name is openCV2.framework, so I assume version is 2.x.x.

But I can not find any clue about the version anymore. 
In the code, no version is mentioned.

I want to know the version for security reason.

Any way to check opencv version in iOS project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you the framework file in the exact version, it is defined in there.

```
std::cout << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
```

(assuming C++)

If you don't have the dependencies, you can only look for strings in the binary or estimate from what features are used.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way of checking OpenCV version if you have access to the project's source code. Just take a look to the file **opencv2.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Info.plist**. Key `CFBundleVersion` contains the version number you are looking for. Here you have the contents of said file for version **4.1.0**:

[image: Info.plist for OpenCV 4.1.0]